# USB PD when load requires more than 5V/15W at startup

Tags: power, usb

I know enough about USB PD 3.X to know what voltages and currents  it can delivere. I also know that the default voltage is 5.0 V (3.0 A)  What do you do if the device requires more than 15 W to boot up and request/negotiate for more power? Do they make a buck converter IC that can negotiate this (based on a pin) and not supply voltage to the rest of the circuit until the power is delivered?

Are there any buck converter ICs that can handle a nominal 15 V input and produce a 3.3 V or 5 V output at <500 mA without an additional drive FET or coil?

Comment: Welcome! By UC, do you mean IC?

Comment: There are USB PD controller ICs that can be configured for a certain power consumer profile via pin strapping and control a load switch and power-good outputs when a suitable negotiation has been done.

Answer (score 3):

You design the device so that it doesn't require 15W just to boot up enough to talk to the power supply.  Until you have negotiated with the power supply, assume a maximum of 5V, 500mA (i.e. 2.5W).  Given how many USB devices work happily at that low power, there's do reason yours can't.

So power off anything that isn't actually needed for communication until you have successfully negotiated more power.  If the USB source can't supply enough power, then the device isn't going to work anyway.

I'm not sure how you're planning to make a buck converter without a transistor or coil.

Comment: Simon B :  "If the USB source can't supply enough power, then the device isn't going to work anyway."

USB PD V3.1 specs power delivery to well over 100W, if the source is capable.